# Regex to match string containing certain words but not other

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write a regex that match words containing "foo" or "bar" but not "baz" anywhere in the string.

```
/(foo|bar).*(?!baz)/
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Use `/^(?!.*baz).*(?:foo|bar)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?!.*\bbaz\b).*\b(?:foo|bar)\b
```

`(?!.*\bbaz\b)` is negative lookahead condition to fail the match if word `baz` is found anywhere in your input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7I1XQX/2)

Comment: thanks, how do I have multiple strings in the negative case, like "baz" and "abc"?

Comment: @Nemo you may use: `^(?!.*\b(?:baz|abc)\b).*\b(?:foo|bar)\b`

Comment: not sure this works: `re.match("^(?!.*\bbaz\b).*\b(?:foo|bar)\b", "foo bar")` return None

Comment: @Wang: Use `re.match(r"^(?!.*\bbaz\b).*\b(?:foo|bar)\b", "foo bar")` and read about raw string in Python